# adding a page bundle with `hugo new`

Tags: hugo

I can add a new page with `hugo new posts/new-page`. But I want to add a page bundle. None of the following work

`hugo new posts/2021/10/new-page` creates a single **new-page.md**
`hugo new posts/2021/10/new-page/` does the same as above
`hugo new posts/2021/10/new-page/index.md` works, kind. It creates **index.md** in the correct path and populates **index.md** with the `archetypes/default.md` *except*, it set the title to **index** instead of **new page**

so, how can I add a page bundle with `hugo new`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using **Archetypes** , quoting from the [docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/archetypes/#directory-based-archetypes):

> Since Hugo 0.49 you can use complete directories as archetype templates.

- in the `archetypes/` folder create a new folder named `post-bundle/`
- inside it create a new file `index.md`

archetypes/post-bundle/**index.md** :

```
---
title: "{{ replace .Name "-" " " | title }}"
date: {{ .Date }}
draft: true
---
```

- Then to create a page bundle:
  `hugo new --kind post-bundle posts/new-page`

**Notice**: I don't think the approach you're doing to set the date in the url is correct , the above method will give a post with the following Permalink : `example.com/posts/new-page` you can then [do the following](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#permalinks-configuration-example) to get the desired Permalink:
**config.toml** :

```
[permalinks]
  posts = '/:year/:month/:title/'
```

Answer (score 1):

In support of Mossab's answer...

a page bundle has three categories:
Branch,
headless
and leaf.

So if you made a file _index.md - it's a Branch bundle, off-the-bat. So viola that's how you make it with hugo new.

If you want a headless bundle, I believe you first need a leaf bundle, and then add:
headless = true to the front matter.

If you want a lead bundle you create an index.md file at any directory level.

So, I believe my point in this is, the way you do this is:

hugo new _index.md
Or
hugo new index.md

and if you want it headless, you use an archetype with the front matter (as Mossab desribes).

Please let me know if I'm possibly misunderstanding something.